# complex analysis multiple choice question

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $\langle z_n \rangle_{n\ge0}$ is a sequence of complex numbers such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z_n$ converges,Given that $f$ is an entire function such that $f(z_n)=n$, then

1. $f\equiv 0$.
2. $f$ is unbounded.
3. No such $f$ exists.
4. $f$ has no zeroes.

Comment: Hint: convergence of the series implies convergence of its terms to zero.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Look into Liouville's Theorem. You may find it helpful.

Comment: @GerryMyerson $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(z_n)=n\Rightarrow f(0)=\infty$ so $f$ is unbounded.

Comment: It's unbounded, but it's unbounded on a sequence of inputs converging to zero, so it's not entire since it has no finite value at zero, so it doesn't exist.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Gerry pointed out, $z_n \rightarrow 0$.  Entire functions are continuous, so think about what we can say about $f(0)$.

Also, what you have written about $g(z)$ doesn't make any sense.  You can't say $g(z) = f(z) - n$ has zeros at all of the $z_k$ because for the definition of $g(z)$ to make sense, $n$ must be fixed.  So it would have a zero at $z_n$ but not at $z_k$ if $k \neq n$.

Comment: $f(0)=0$, according to the question.

Comment: It doesn't say that anywhere in the question you posted.

Comment: oh! I see I am very sorry.

Comment: I must agree that I should take $g(z)=f(z)-z$ right?and then all $z_n$ will be zeroes of $g$.